# Installing other PHP app in sub directory

Tags: server, routing, configuration

My question is the opposite of this question: [Installing Craft in sub directory](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/installing-craft-in-sub-directory)

I have a Craft website and I need to put a Laravel application in a sub directory, it almost works. I have made the directory and created a symbolic link to the public folder for the Laravel application.

This works with the default route in Laravel but as soon as I try any nested routes I just get a Craft 404.

Is is possible to get Craft to completely ignore a folder or something, or do I need to figure out an alternative solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, possible. You just need to override the URL routing within the subdirectory, so requests to /sub/* get routed to /sub/index.php rather than /index.php.

For example, if you’re using Apache, just place Laravel’s [.htaccess file](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls) within your subdirectory.